# Upgrading Windows 8.1 to 10 changes bootcamp partition to disk0s4

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I recently upgraded my Windows 8.1 Pro on bootcamp to Windows 10 successfully. However when I booted back into Mac, the bootcamp partition had disappeared in the finder window. When I checked disk utility, the partition that was once named Bootcamp, is now named disk0s4!

There is also an error saying:

**Error: This Disk needs to be repaired. Click Repair Disk.**

I also have a boot manager installed (rEFInd), which now is bypassed when I restart the machine, however when I hold option the windows drive appears and I can boot into it!

Is this something to do with bootcamp drivers support for windows 10?
Would the problem be solved by doing a clean install of windows 10 instead of upgrading?

Comment: I certainly won't be advising anyone to update to Windows 10 until Bootcamp supports it. I (foolishly) tried to as well, but (probably luckily) the upgrade failed due to Win10 not having a driver for my mid-2015 MBP's FaceTime camera, and it successfully rolled itself back to 8.1 before I caused any more problems for myself :)

Comment: @scottishwildcat damn, how long do you think it will take them to support it?

Comment: Good question... hopefully it'll happen along with the El Capitan release at the latest. Then again, Windows 8 was released in August 2012, and BootCamp didn't support it until March 2013 :/

Comment: hopefully, i think ill just revert back to 8.1 for now, cheers for the reply though!

Comment: Good news, they updated BootCamp today! https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990